# GIT-SVN every attempted commit results in <file-name> needs update

Tags: git, svn

I am attempting to commit changes made locally to a remote repository using git-bash

> git svn dcommit

results in

```
 <filename>: needs update
 update-index --refresh: command returned error: 1
```

I have tortoiseGIT installed on my machine, and if I do the commit by rightclicking my local repository and Git Commit -> Master...
then the commit works fine.

2 questions, is this the same as doing a git svn dcommit?

and, why am I getting the error from teh command line?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasnt really aware of the order that I needed to do things to make a commit.

I now do the following steps to make a remote commit and it works fine:

```
git commit -a
```

I then add a note to the commit as prompted. I had trouble figuring out the VIM format, but the steps to add a note are press 'i' to get to 'Insert' mode. Add my note, press 'esc', type :x to save my note.

```
git svn dcommit
```

and Voila! everything works!

Answer (score 1):

You should read this http://juststuffreally.blogspot.com/2008/10/how-to-git-svn-dcommit-with-local.html
This is the right solution if you really do not want to commit those unstaged files